# Concrete5: Problems when adding a new block type

Tags: block, concrete5

I've just made a new installation of concrete (5.6), and all of a sudden I'm failing Concrete 101's.

I created a new block type, when I went to install it I got this...

> Warning: require_once(/...[concrete
>   root].../concrete/blocks/basic_test/controller.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /...[concrete
>   root].../concrete/core/models/block_types.php on line 824

I eventually deleted my block and copied across the basic_test block 
(http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/blocks/understanding-and-building-blocks-in-concrete5).

To my surprise the error persisted.

I'm placing my blocks where I always have concrete root /blocks yet for some reason its looking for resources under concrete root /concrete/blocks.

Now I'm just confused at having failed so completely at such a simple task.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug In 5.6.0 related to the new overrides cache. It was fixed in the 5.6.0.1 point release, so upgrading should resolve the issue. Or you can turn off the override cache in the dashboard if you don't want to upgrade.

Comment: I updated to 5.6.0.1, didn't work, then turned off the overrides cache which solved the issue.

Thanks kindly

Comment: You should be able to clear the cache to resolve this in 5.6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

My steps to fix this exception:

1. Turn off override and basic cache
2. Uninstall "corrupt" package
3. Clear cache
4. **Delete your block row from the "BlockTypes" table** VERY IMPORTANT
5. Reinstall package